# wget unable to download with dynamic session ID

Tags: session, session-cookies, wget

I have been using Wget to pull the warranty information from my website using the following command.

```
wget -q -O getinfo.tmp "http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/warrantyLookup.do?type=$TYPE&serial=$SERIAL&country=897&iws=off"
```

Now IBM has changed the URL and provided with the dynamic session ID

The new URL, `http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/wlup`
stopped working some time ago when IBM changed the site to use dynamic session IDs.  I would love to be able to do this again.

You can use your machine type and serial to get the information or I can provide the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doubting this will work

--keep-session-cookies

but it may.

Quickly looking at the site you'd have to do something more complex involving scraping the site and looking for the dynamic URL.  Though, if IBM is trying to prevent automation of this form, perhaps you should consider not automating access to this form.